# Input in header for search in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a Header component, with an Input element. I want to search into an array which is in another component, that is an product list. Both are connected by the App.js. How can I pass the input value to the target component to search something in the array? I need to show the searched products in the screen, how to force render the target component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommand you to use a context if you need to access your data in multiple components. Now if it's exceptional, you could do it this way :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [searchedValue, setSearchedValue] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <Header setSearchedValue={setSearchedValue} />
      <Child searchedValue={searchedValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = ({ setSearchedValue }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const inputRef = React.createRef();

  const search = () => setSearchedValue(inputValue);

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: "#A00F0F" }}>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={inputRef}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={() => setInputValue(inputRef.current.value)}
        placeholder="search by id"
      />
      <button onClick={search}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ searchedValue }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { id: 0, name: "item1" },
    { id: 1, name: "item2" },
    { id: 2, name: "item3" }
  ]);
  const [searchedItem, setSearchedItem] = React.useState(data[0]);

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      setSearchedItem(data.filter(item => item.id == searchedValue)[0]); // Note the double equal instead of triple, i don't wantto compare type, do as you wish
    }, 
    [searchedValue]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>searchedValue = {searchedValue}</div>
      <div>Item name = {searchedItem ? searchedItem.name : null }</div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the [repro on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-amfzmq?file=index.js).

Your data are in the Child component. So you need to retrieve the value from your header input to your App component (in a state to make it render correctly) and then just pass the searched value to your child component.

Answer (score 0):

If both are connected by a parent component you can declare the array there with a callback to get called when the search is trigger and if you want to show the matched products you should have a state variable that gets updated on every search within the callback and you can pass the matched products to the Target component with props.

Comment: I've already passed with props, but does not re-render :/

Comment: try to post your code